# How do you load an alternate jquery in a webpack module?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, typescript, webpack

I need to load alternate versions of jQuery other than the one in my node_modules. I have a local copy of the script but I am unable to get it to load in my webpack app.ts. I have removed the global jQuery and resolve path for node_modules in my webpack config since I do not want the version from node_modules. However I can't figure out how I can pass the loaded jquery to the scripts that require it.

I have multiple entry points (app.ts) each which needs to be able to load a different jquery so I can not define jquery in the webpack config as I would like to use the same config for processing all my entry points.

app.ts

```
import jquery from '../../../js/jquery-3.3.1.js';

// tried this but didn't help
// window.$ = jquery;
// window.jquery = jquery;

// these two require jquery but fail, it only works if I add back in
// the webpack config to find jquery in node_modules which is what I 
// don't want. popper.js has the same issue as jquery.
import '../../../js/popper-1.12.9.min.js';
import '../../../js/bootstrap-4.0.0.js';
import './js/jquery.matchHeight-min.js';

...
```

Comment: Use`resolve.alias`

Comment: Wouldn't that limit me to one jquery version as it would be globaly defined in the webpack. config? If I define an alias for each version (e.g. `jquery311`) how would I get it into `jquery.matchHeight-min.js` as `jquery`?

Answer (score 1):

I think there are several approaches to this issue.

- Add some scripting. It's possible to create a simple function that will set different `resolve.alias` values for different given `entry` points. and then use `ProvidePlugin` or even `imports-loader` in order to do shimming and set it globally. [shimming docs](https://webpack.js.org/guides/shimming/)
- Use [expose-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/expose-loader). with that you can require different scripts yet they all will be exposed with the same variable name.